# \begin{titlepage} question

Tags: page-breaking, titles, page

I am trying to write a CV where I have a title followed by text within the same page. I have the title but it won't let me write in the same page. Is this because the `\begin{titlepage}` command commits a page solely for the text enclosed within it? Is there any way to stop the page break?

How can I make the work experience section appear in the same page? Do I have to use `\maketitle` instead in the preamble or is there a way I can stick with `\begin{titlepage}`?

```
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
    \line(1,0){300}\\
    [5mm]
    \Huge Curriculum Vitae\\
    [5mm]
    \Large\textbf{NAME}\\
    [3mm]
    EMAIL\\
    PHONE\\
    \hrulefill
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}\nopagebreak

Text Text Text Text etc
```

Comment: A picture of your code is less useful than the actual code itself, as it cannot be copied for people to experiment with while trying to answer your question.  However, I do not think titlepage is what you are looking for for a CV - it is used moreso, say, for a thesis, where a title page is needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why not just paste the code without embedding it into the 'titlepage' environment? If spacing is a problem, you can solve it with `\hspace' and other macros.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

I was using the `\titlepage` function when I should have been using `\title` and `\maketitle` after I begun the document. `\titlepage` dedicated a whole page to the title itself and nothing else; seems stunningly self-explanatory on this one ... woops!